# Using JavaFX DatePicker in Eclipse SwingBuilder

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, javafx, windowbuilder

I'm trying to design an application using a combination of JavaFX and Swing components, initially I created a Swing project and am trying to integrate a JavaFX `javafx.scene.control.DatePicker` control.

I read elsewhere that I should be able to do this with a `javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel` so I created a new `JPanel` and using Eclipses WindowBuilder added a `JFXPanel` but when I added a `DatePicker` Eclipse throws an error.

I am using the latest version of JRE/JDK.

The code looks like this;

```
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel;
import javafx.scene.control.DatePicker;

public class test extends JPanel {
    /**
     * @wbp.nonvisual location=99,99
     */
    private final DatePicker datePicker = new DatePicker();

    /**
     * Create the panel.
     */
    public test() {

        JFXPanel panel = new JFXPanel();
        add(panel);

    }

}
```

When I look at the design view;

```
Exception during constructor evaluation

An exception happened during evaluation of

new DatePicker()
Constructor DatePicker() was used with the parameters {}. 
Note: null values may occur when parsing complex expressions that can't be resolved at design-time. java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class javafx.scene.control.DatePicker





Hide stack trace. 



Stack trace:
org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.utils.exception.DesignerException: 307 (Exception during constructor evaluation). new DatePicker() DatePicker() {} java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class javafx.scene.control.DatePicker
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.eval.evaluators.InvocationEvaluator.createConstructorProblemException(InvocationEvaluator.java:593)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.eval.evaluators.InvocationEvaluator.evaluate(InvocationEvaluator.java:268)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.eval.evaluators.InvocationEvaluator.evaluate(InvocationEvaluator.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.wb.core.eval.AstEvaluationEngine.evaluate0(AstEvaluationEngine.java:177)
    at org.eclipse.wb.core.eval.AstEvaluationEngine.evaluate(AstEvaluationEngine.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.model.JavaInfoEvaluationHelper.evaluateExpression(JavaInfoEvaluationHelper.java:630)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.model.JavaInfoEvaluationHelper.evaluate(JavaInfoEvaluationHelper.java:502)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.parser.JavaInfoParser.evaluateNode(JavaInfoParser.java:1309)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.parser.JavaInfoParser.access$1(JavaInfoParser.java:1300)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.parser.JavaInfoParser$ExecutionFlowParseVisitor$3.run(JavaInfoParser.java:602)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.utils.execution.ExecutionUtils.runRethrow(ExecutionUtils.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.parser.JavaInfoParser$ExecutionFlowParseVisitor.postVisit(JavaInfoParser.java:592)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTNode.accept(ASTNode.java:2714)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTNode.acceptChild(ASTNode.java:2759)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.VariableDeclarationFragment.accept0(VariableDeclarationFragment.java:263)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTNode.accept(ASTNode.java:2711)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTNode.acceptChildren(ASTNode.java:2782)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.FieldDeclaration.accept0(FieldDeclaration.java:289)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTNode.accept(ASTNode.java:2711)
    at org.eclipse.wb.core.eval.ExecutionFlowUtils.visitFields(ExecutionFlowUtils.java:267)
    at org.eclipse.wb.core.eval.ExecutionFlowUtils.visit(ExecutionFlowUtils.java:223)
    at org.eclipse.wb.core.eval.ExecutionFlowUtils.visit(ExecutionFlowUtils.java:191)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.parser.JavaInfoParser.parseRootMethods(JavaInfoParser.java:312)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.parser.JavaInfoParser.parse(JavaInfoParser.java:268)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.parser.JavaInfoParser.access$9(JavaInfoParser.java:238)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.parser.JavaInfoParser$1.runObject(JavaInfoParser.java:153)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.parser.JavaInfoParser$1.runObject(JavaInfoParser.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.utils.execution.ExecutionUtils.runDesignTime(ExecutionUtils.java:159)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.parser.JavaInfoParser.parse(JavaInfoParser.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.DesignPage.internal_refreshGEF(DesignPage.java:534)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.DesignPage.access$9(DesignPage.java:522)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.DesignPage$8$1.run(DesignPage.java:449)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.syncExec(Synchronizer.java:186)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.UISynchronizer.syncExec(UISynchronizer.java:145)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.syncExec(Display.java:4761)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.DesignPage$8.run(DesignPage.java:446)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.runInCurrentThread(ModalContext.java:463)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.run(ModalContext.java:371)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.ProgressMonitorDialog.run(ProgressMonitorDialog.java:500)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.DesignPage.internal_refreshGEF_withProgress(DesignPage.java:465)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.DesignPage.internal_refreshGEF(DesignPage.java:415)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.UndoManager.refreshDesignerEditor(UndoManager.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.UndoManager.activate(UndoManager.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.DesignPage.handleActiveState_True(DesignPage.java:263)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.DesignPage.handleActiveState(DesignPage.java:241)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.multi.DefaultMultiMode.showPage(DefaultMultiMode.java:125)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.multi.DefaultMultiMode$1.widgetSelected(DefaultMultiMode.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:248)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4362)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1113)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1137)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1122)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.notifyListeners(Widget.java:788)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder.setSelection(CTabFolder.java:3158)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder.onMouse(CTabFolder.java:1841)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder$1.handleEvent(CTabFolder.java:330)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4362)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1113)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4180)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3769)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$4.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1127)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:337)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1018)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:654)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:337)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:598)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:139)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:669)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:608)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1515)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class javafx.scene.control.DatePicker
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.eval.evaluators.InvocationEvaluator.evaluate(InvocationEvaluator.java:262)
    ... 81 more


Full context stack trace:
java.lang.Error: new DatePicker()
    at org.eclipse.wb.core.eval.AstEvaluationEngine.evaluate(AstEvaluationEngine.java:71)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.model.JavaInfoEvaluationHelper.evaluateExpression(JavaInfoEvaluationHelper.java:630)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.model.JavaInfoEvaluationHelper.evaluate(JavaInfoEvaluationHelper.java:502)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.parser.JavaInfoParser.evaluateNode(JavaInfoParser.java:1309)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.parser.JavaInfoParser.access$1(JavaInfoParser.java:1300)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.parser.JavaInfoParser$ExecutionFlowParseVisitor$3.run(JavaInfoParser.java:602)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.utils.execution.ExecutionUtils.runRethrow(ExecutionUtils.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.parser.JavaInfoParser$ExecutionFlowParseVisitor.postVisit(JavaInfoParser.java:592)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTNode.accept(ASTNode.java:2714)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTNode.acceptChild(ASTNode.java:2759)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.VariableDeclarationFragment.accept0(VariableDeclarationFragment.java:263)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTNode.accept(ASTNode.java:2711)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTNode.acceptChildren(ASTNode.java:2782)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.FieldDeclaration.accept0(FieldDeclaration.java:289)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTNode.accept(ASTNode.java:2711)
    at org.eclipse.wb.core.eval.ExecutionFlowUtils.visitFields(ExecutionFlowUtils.java:267)
    at org.eclipse.wb.core.eval.ExecutionFlowUtils.visit(ExecutionFlowUtils.java:223)
    at org.eclipse.wb.core.eval.ExecutionFlowUtils.visit(ExecutionFlowUtils.java:191)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.parser.JavaInfoParser.parseRootMethods(JavaInfoParser.java:312)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.parser.JavaInfoParser.parse(JavaInfoParser.java:268)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.parser.JavaInfoParser.access$9(JavaInfoParser.java:238)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.parser.JavaInfoParser$1.runObject(JavaInfoParser.java:153)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.parser.JavaInfoParser$1.runObject(JavaInfoParser.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.utils.execution.ExecutionUtils.runDesignTime(ExecutionUtils.java:159)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.parser.JavaInfoParser.parse(JavaInfoParser.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.DesignPage.internal_refreshGEF(DesignPage.java:534)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.DesignPage.access$9(DesignPage.java:522)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.DesignPage$8$1.run(DesignPage.java:449)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.syncExec(Synchronizer.java:186)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.UISynchronizer.syncExec(UISynchronizer.java:145)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.syncExec(Display.java:4761)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.DesignPage$8.run(DesignPage.java:446)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.runInCurrentThread(ModalContext.java:463)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.run(ModalContext.java:371)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.ProgressMonitorDialog.run(ProgressMonitorDialog.java:500)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.DesignPage.internal_refreshGEF_withProgress(DesignPage.java:465)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.DesignPage.internal_refreshGEF(DesignPage.java:415)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.UndoManager.refreshDesignerEditor(UndoManager.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.UndoManager.activate(UndoManager.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.DesignPage.handleActiveState_True(DesignPage.java:263)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.DesignPage.handleActiveState(DesignPage.java:241)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.multi.DefaultMultiMode.showPage(DefaultMultiMode.java:125)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.multi.DefaultMultiMode$1.widgetSelected(DefaultMultiMode.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:248)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4362)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1113)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1137)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1122)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.notifyListeners(Widget.java:788)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder.setSelection(CTabFolder.java:3158)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder.onMouse(CTabFolder.java:1841)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder$1.handleEvent(CTabFolder.java:330)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4362)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1113)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4180)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3769)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$4.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1127)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:337)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1018)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:654)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:337)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:598)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:139)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:669)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:608)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1515)
Caused by: org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.utils.exception.DesignerException: 307 (Exception during constructor evaluation). new DatePicker() DatePicker() {} java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class javafx.scene.control.DatePicker
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.eval.evaluators.InvocationEvaluator.createConstructorProblemException(InvocationEvaluator.java:593)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.eval.evaluators.InvocationEvaluator.evaluate(InvocationEvaluator.java:268)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.eval.evaluators.InvocationEvaluator.evaluate(InvocationEvaluator.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.wb.core.eval.AstEvaluationEngine.evaluate0(AstEvaluationEngine.java:177)
    at org.eclipse.wb.core.eval.AstEvaluationEngine.evaluate(AstEvaluationEngine.java:61)
    ... 78 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class javafx.scene.control.DatePicker
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.eval.evaluators.InvocationEvaluator.evaluate(InvocationEvaluator.java:262)
    ... 81 more
```

Is there a simple solution to getting this working, or perhaps I should use a different component for date time selection?

Comment: This seems to be mainly a problem with Eclipse's WindowBuilder which might not be able to handle the integration of JavaFX.

Comment: Right, so i installed [e(fx)clipse](http://www.eclipse.org/efxclipse/index.html) that is supposed to allow integration and allowed me to add the components to the palette and drag and drop the components onto the panel.